# Is There Any Way Without File.ReadAllText?

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-mobile-5.0

As I love to develop file I/O applications and my new development platform is Windows Mobile. Is there any way to read all the file, without using `File.ReadAllText`?

Because Windows Mobile doesn't have this function.

Comment: Have you tried reading the File class documentation for the mobile platform?

Comment: @Lazarus:  Where can the documentation of the File class for the mobile platform be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your own:

```
static string ReadAllText(string path) {
    using (var r = new StreamReader(path)) {
        return r.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm going to build a library of this, to use in future projects.

Comment: Good, I highly recommend building up a personal "augment library" that fixes missing bits from the BCL. But it's also important to learn the IO library in and out - saves a lot of time.

Comment: To keep its size down, the BCL omits methods that are just short-cuts, like File.ReadAllText, where is simple enough to write your own version.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the file operations are supported by the mobile framework, for example:

```
string text;
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName)) {
   text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```